ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymatgen.analysis.interface'
This import causes an error:
from pymatgen.analysis.interface import get_interface

But these imports work fine:
from pymatgen.core.structure import Structure
from pymatgen.core.surface import SlabGenerator

I am trying to run this in google colab, but I get the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymatgen.analysis.interface'. How can I solve this problem?

Change to pymatgen.analysis.interfaces (interfaces vs interface)
